# c# convert 2 bytes into int value

Tags: c#, arrays

First, I had read many posts and tried BitConverter methods for the conversion, but I haven't got the desired result.
From a 2 byte array of:

```
byte[] dateArray = new byte[] { 0x07 , 0xE4 };
```

Y need to get an integer with value 2020. So, the decimal of 0x7E4.

Following method does not returning the desired value,

```
int i1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(dateArray, 0);
```

Comment: That's not 2020. The bytes are reversed. 2020 is `0x07E4` while the array stores `0x07` in the *lower* byte - that's `0xE407`

Comment: you need to reverse edit: example is in bitconverter documentation

Comment: Maybe the endianess of your system is the problem. You can try `int i1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(dateArray.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);`

Comment: int i1 = dateArray[0] << 8 | dateArray[1];  You may need to reverse the order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The endianess tells you how numbers are stored on your computer. There are two possibilities: Little endian and big endian.

Big endian means the biggest byte is stored first, i.e. 2020 would become 0x07, 0xE4.
Little endian means the lowest byte is stored first, i.e. 2020 would become 0xE4, 0x07.

Most computers are little endian, hence the other way round a human would expect. With `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`, you can check which type of endianess your computer has. Your code would become:

```cs
byte[] dateArray = new byte[] { 0x07 , 0xE4 };
if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    Array.Reverse(dataArray);
}
int i1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(dateArray, 0);
```

Comment: Works well, thank you for the answer and also for the explanation of little endian. Really thankful

Answer (score 1):

```
dateArray[0] << 8 | dateArray[1]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thank you. It is working if I reverse the order, dateArray[1] << 8 | dateArray[0]. Probably because of the little endian. +1 for a working solution, however I am going to use the one that handles the little endian. Really thankful